# php php_replace regex \\\ forward slash

Tags: php, api, amazon-product-api

I'm calling an Amazon API to get a URL to book cover thumbnails.

The thumbnail URL comes back like this:

```
\\ebc.amazon.com\images\EtcLkasff-_-23.jpg
```

The forward slashes are the problem. To make these images show up on my page is replace the "\" with a "/". But, my regex php_replace syntax is failing me.

I've got this:

```
$thumbnail = str_replace('\', '//', $apiString);
```

I've tried

```
$thumbnail = str_replace('\\', '//', $apiString);
```

and it still doesn't work.

Thanks in advance, everyone!!

EDIT:::

after I do:

```
$thumbnail = "http://" . $thumbnail;
```

The URL looks like this:

```
http://\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51vCLCTcmAL._SL75_.jpg
```

I've tried

```
$picture4 = str_replace('\', '/', $picture4);
```

This gives me an escape error.

**I'm sorry :( One more edit to make things perfectly clear:**

I've done this:

```
       // get amazon picture URL
        $picture1 = preg_split('/,/', str_replace("\"", "", $details));
        $picture2 = preg_split('/:/', $picture1[7]);
        $picture3 = preg_replace('/\\//','/',$picture2[2]);
        $picture4 = preg_replace('/\\//','/',$picture3);
//        $picture4 = str_replace('\', '/', $picture4);
        $picture4 = "http://" . $picture4;

         echo "<pre>";print_r($picture4);echo "</pre>";
```

At this point, $picture4 is:

http://\/\/ecx.images-amazon.com\/images\/I\/51vCLCTcmAL.*SL75*.jpg

Comment: like @Wesley Murch has stated, you only need to use his answer. You cannot use Reg-Expressions with this function. If you really want to use reg-ex, try the preg_split function. But str_replace is better here.

Comment: I used php_split earlier in the API results. 
       // get amazon picture URL
        $picture1 = preg_split('/,/', str_replace("\"", "", $details));
        $picture2 = preg_split('/:/', $picture1[7]);
        $picture3 = preg_replace('/\\//','/',$picture2[2]);
        $picture4 = preg_replace('/\\//','/',$picture3);
//        $picture4 = str_replace('\', '/', $picture4);
        $picture4 = "http://" . $picture4;

         echo "<pre>";print_r($picture4);echo "</pre>";

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://codepad.org/t7PGsE89) should really be all you need:

```
$thumbnail = str_replace('\\', '/', $apiString);
//                        ^^^ the backslash must be escaped
```

This would convert:

> `\\ebc.amazon.com\images\EtcLkasff-_-23.jpg`

to

> `//ebc.amazon.com/images/EtcLkasff-_-23.jpg`

Comment: Sorry, Wesley, but this gives me an error. I tried it before I asked for help. I get an escape error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in /home/www/class/api.php on line 81

Comment: I edit the original post. Hopefully what I've done wrong will be obvious now. I've been banging my head against the wall for so long with this! I'm sure it's something tiny I've missed... 

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you, Wesley! That did do it! It works in Firefox now!

My URL string has way too many backslashes, but it still works... Will this be a problem in IE or Chrome? URL:

http://////ecx.images-amazon.com//images//I//51vCLCTcmAL._SL75_.jpg

Comment: @SquireCD: You should get rid of those extra ones, why are they there? All you need is the code I provided, with `http:` in the front. In fact, you can leave out the `http:` altogether and it should still work.